# How to find related Hadiths for any Sura or Quran verse?

Tags: quran, hadith, surah, verses

As Hadiths elaborates and describes the meanings of Quran's suras/verses, to understand any particular sura/verse, how can someone directly find the related Hadiths?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have used qtafsir.com extensively, to help me understand the Qur'an better. It is an online version of Tafsir Ibn Kathir. He refers quite often to the hadith, although he doesn't usually say which specific hadith. I realize this is not exactly what you're requesting, but hopefully it could be somewhat useful to you.

Comment: Also, although it involves some extra work, I have sometimes been able to find the specific hadith simply by googling for Ibn Kathir's hadith quotes. Sometimes that will point you to a site such as sunnah.com, where you can sometimes find the hadith you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is to consult a work of [Tafsir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tafsir_works), as the comprehensive ones among them will cite any relevant hadith.

Some hadith collections have a dedicated book on tafsir of Quranic verses, for example the كتاب التفسير of [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/65) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/56) etc.

Answer (score -1):

Salamo Alaikom,

Dear sir, just to correct you the Hadiths is not ment to describe the meanings of Quran's verses, yes some of it but the Hadiths complete the Quran, it talk about the things that the Quran not mentioned or said any judge on it, so in order to understand the meanings of Quran's verses i suggest that you buy or read books that describes suras and verses  for example `Tafsir Ibn Kathir`

Comment: Walaikum As-salam. Okay, may be I have mixed the definition of Hadith and Tafsir. But is it possible to find related hadiths of a sura, easily. As while suras were recited/described by Muhammad (PBUH), he also answered some questions of sahabi's (his followers). And as I know everything Muhammad (PBUH) said and did is Hadith.

Comment: you could read Tafsir Durre Mansoor By Imam Jalaluddin Al-Suyuti you will find there related hadith as per your satisfaction In Sha Allah.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the site [QuranX](http://quranx.com/). When you browse to a particular Quranic verse, you'll find related *tafsirs* and *hadiths* by clicking on the options above it. For example, if you want the hadiths related to Quran 4:34, you can click [here](http://quranx.com/4.34).

[image]